# Haar measure property

Tags: measure-theory, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, and let $\mu$ be a radon measure. I wanna show that the
The measure $\mu$ is a left Haar measure on $G$ if and only if the measure $\tilde{\mu}$, defined
by $\tilde{\mu}(A) = \mu(A^{−1})$ for $A \in \mathcal B$, is a right Haar measure on $G$.

We can observe the following:
$$\tilde{\mu}(gA)=\mu((gA)^{-1})=\mu(A^{-1} 
g^{-1} )$$
Furthermore we have that $g \mapsto g^{-1}$ is a bijection but how can I now conclude? Many thanks for some help!

EDIT: I found this one:
[image]

Does the last if and only if holds because $g\mapsto g^{-1}$ is a bijection?

Comment: Yes, it's because $g^{-1}$ runs through the whole group whence $g\in G$ does so.